# Manually run "Run" registry entries on windows

Tags: windows, shell, windows-explorer, autorun

I am developing an appliance for a company. I have to develop a custom "explorer.exe" to be run as the shell. The problem is that the current explorer does some import operations such as processing the "Run" (and RunOnce, which I don't actually need) registry entries at the following location.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Is there a separate exe/command in windows to manually run these items that I can invoke from my custom explorer.exe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope. Just open the key, iterate the sub-keys and run the specified commands.

Comment: @EBGreen I'd say add that as an answer. :)

Comment: I generally only add answers if I have either dealt with the specific issue before or I have spent some effort in testing. I've never had the need to explore the WIN32 API for this specific answer, but I'm 90% sure it is correct.

Answer (score -1):

[Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

A step-by-step tutorial on writing shell extensions:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on writing a shell extension that operates on multiple files at once:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/445/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on writing a shell extension that shows pop-up info for files:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part III](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/448/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on writing a shell extension that provides custom drag and drop functionality:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part IV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on writing a shell extension that adds pages to the properties dialog of files:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part V](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on writing a shell extension that can be used on the Send To menu:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part VI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/485/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on using owner-drawn menus in a context menu shell extensions, and on making a context menu extension that responds to a right-click in a directory background:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part VII](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/711/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on adding columns to Explorer's details view via a column handler shell extension:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part VIII](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/722/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

A tutorial on writing an extension to customize the icons displayed for a file type:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part IX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

Simple way:

Replace default shell

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Shell REG_SZ <application>
```